# does order of function definitions in IntelliJ IDEA's scala worksheet matter?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, jvm, sbt

I am trying to evaluate a Scala worksheet (sbt 1.5.5, jvm adopt@1.11.0-11, Scala 3.0.1) in IntelliJ IDEA. The `worksheet.sc`, if defined as follows

```scala
def abs(x:Double) = if (x < 0) -x else x

def sqrtIter(guess: Double, x: Double): Double =
  if (isGoodEnough(guess, x)) guess
  else sqrtIter(improve(guess, x), x)

def isGoodEnough(guess: Double, x: Double) =
  abs(guess * guess - x ) / x < 0.001

def improve(guess: Double, x: Double) =(guess + x / guess) / 2
```

does throw some errors when evaluated: `Not found: isGoodEnough` and `Not found: improve`.
However, if I move the definition of those two functions **above** `sqrtIter`, it runs correctly.

Does the order of functions' definition matter?

Comment: Yes, worksheet can be though of being similar to writing things on scala REPL. The REPL can not know what is going to be typed in future.

Comment: I think you answered your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, order does matter when using Scala worksheets having Run Type as REPL.

From the comments below:
**Show worksheet settings** (click on wrench icon found upper left). Change **Run type** from REPL to Plain. Your code will compile as posted (no need to reorder).

Comment: **Show worksheet settings** (click on wrench icon found upper left). Change **Run type** from **REPL** to **Plain**. Your code will compile as posted (no need to reorder).